# Convert csv file which is pipe delimited to JSON format

Tags: python, json, csv

I am trying to convert CSV file which is pipe delimited to JSON file and SetrecordID will be List and Pairs will be list of dictionaries.

**CSV Input File**

```
SetrecordID|SetMatchScore|Pairs
100,101,102|90|"100-101,40","100-102,80","101-102,90"
103,104,105|80|"103-104,60","103-105,90","104-105,90"
106,107,108|65|"106-107,55","106-108,60","107-108,80"
109,110,111|95|"109-110,85","109-111,100","110-111,100"
```

**Expected output in JSON**

```
[
    {
        Date: system date
        SetrecordID:[100,101,102]
        SetMatchScore:90
        Pairs:[
            {Pair1:100-101,matchscore:40},
            {Pair2:100-102,matchscore:80},
            {Pair3:101-102,matchscore:90}
              ]
    },
    {
        Date: system date
        SetrecordID:[103,104,105]
        SetMatchScore:90
        Pairs:[
            {Pair1:103-104,matchscore:60},
            {Pair2:103-105,matchscore:90},
            {Pair3:104-105,matchscore:90}
              ]
    }
]
```

**Getting Output in JSON**

```
   {
   "SetrecordID":[
      "109",
      "110",
      "111"
   ],
   "SetMatchScore":95,
   "Pairs":"109-110,85,\"109-111,100\",\"110-111,100\""
}
```

**Code Tried**

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv',sep="|")
dict_val = {}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
row["SetrecordID"] = row["SetrecordID"].split(",")
dict_val.update(row)
```

print(dict_val)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Pandas won't help you here. (Happily, you also don't need Pandas here.)

```
import csv, io, ast, json

# Using a `StringIO` here instead of reading from a file
# (but since `StringIO`s are file-like, you can substitute
#  an `open()` call here.)

data = io.StringIO(
    """
SetrecordID|SetMatchScore|Pairs
100,101,102|90|"100-101,40","100-102,80","101-102,90"
103,104,105|80|"103-104,60","103-105,90","104-105,90"
106,107,108|65|"106-107,55","106-108,60","107-108,80"
109,110,111|95|"109-110,85","109-111,100","110-111,100"
""".strip()
)

rows = []

for row in csv.DictReader(data, delimiter="|", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE):
    pairs = [pair.split(",", 1) for pair in ast.literal_eval(row["Pairs"])]
    row["Pairs"] = [
        {f"Pair{x}": key, "matchscore": int(val)}
        for x, (key, val) in enumerate(pairs, 1)
    ]
    row["SetrecordID"] = row["SetrecordID"].split(",")
    rows.append(row)

with open("data.json", "w") as outf:
    json.dump(rows, outf, indent=2)
```

will ingest that data to a dicts you can work with (or just output to a JSON file):

```
{'SetrecordID': ['100', '101', '102'], 'SetMatchScore': '90', 'Pairs': [{'Pair1': '100-101', 'matchscore': 40}, {'Pair2': '100-102', 'matchscore': 80}, {'Pair3': '101-102', 'matchscore': 90}]}
{'SetrecordID': ['103', '104', '105'], 'SetMatchScore': '80', 'Pairs': [{'Pair1': '103-104', 'matchscore': 60}, {'Pair2': '103-105', 'matchscore': 90}, {'Pair3': '104-105', 'matchscore': 90}]}
{'SetrecordID': ['106', '107', '108'], 'SetMatchScore': '65', 'Pairs': [{'Pair1': '106-107', 'matchscore': 55}, {'Pair2': '106-108', 'matchscore': 60}, {'Pair3': '107-108', 'matchscore': 80}]}
{'SetrecordID': ['109', '110', '111'], 'SetMatchScore': '95', 'Pairs': [{'Pair1': '109-110', 'matchscore': 85}, {'Pair2': '109-111', 'matchscore': 100}, {'Pair3': '110-111', 'matchscore': 100}]}
```

Comment: It is CSV file and we need to read that way instead of storing data into string.

Comment: Yep. `StringIO`s make filelike objects out of strings. Instead of `data = io.StringIO(...)`, you can `data = open(...)`.

Comment: pairs = [pair.split(",", 1) for pair in ast.literal_eval(row["Pairs"])]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Are you sure you're using `DictReader()`? That sounds like you got a list row, not a dict row. All I can tell you is the code I pasted above works for the data you provided.

Comment: I have updated my code in question. can you please check and let me know the Pairs part .

Comment: ... So you tried an entirely different piece of code than what I suggested here? Why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238096/discussion-between-naveen-and-akx).

Comment: I have tried your code as well and got the error as posted in above comment

Comment: If you copy and paste my code from above into a Python file and run it, I think you should find that it works fine. You can then modify it to use your CSV file instead of the StringIO. If the code fails with some other input in your CSV file, then you can surely fix it.

Comment: now I am getting right output except 1 part. SorucesID are need to be in List

Comment: You have never mentioned a "SorucesID" before. If you mean `SetrecordID`, then that's a `split(",")` away.

Comment: yeah I mean SetrecordId

Comment: See my edit, please.

Comment: Can you please some explanation about the code to understand.

Comment: how to write to json file.

Comment: The code should not be hard to understand for a senior software engineer. Either way, see my edit; it will now write a `data.json` file.

Comment: Code explanation is for everyone on the stackoverflow platform.